# Firebase Database Not Working..No Response

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I'm not be able to access the Database, means Its not giving me any response while I writing into the database. I don't have any Type of authentication just for temporary I use firebase but it's not allowing me to read and write into the database.

Is it compulsory to have the authentication to access the Database?

I also set up the database rules to the auth==null..

Still no response..

My Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference.child("User").setValue(textView.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Are there any error message showing in logcat?

Comment: This Message: 00:18:40.069 10844-10844/com.example.acer.myapplication W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
02-25 00:18:40.082 10844-11332/com.example.acer.myapplication I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
02-25 00:18:40.082 10844-11332/com.example.acer.myapplication I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
02-25

Comment: everytime its shows Firebase Crash is initialized

Comment: 02-25 00:33:02.018 14124-14155/com.example.acer.myapplication W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found. also this

Answer (score 2):

i also faced same problem 1 week after that i found a solution is OFF WIFI and TEST USING MOBILE DATA. it worked form me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
Read == true
Write == true
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Google Play Services version.

For firebase to work, it needs :-

1. Android device with Google Play services 11.8.0 or above
2. Android Studio version 2.2 or later
3. Google Play Services from the Android SDK Manager
4. Android Studio project and its package name

Make sure you are using all the right version of dependencies, check here [Firebase Prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites)

For now have these rules,

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
   }
}
```

And finally, make sure you are connected to internet because Google Play Services API does a download at the first time it is used.

Comment: I have checked the requirement it's all correct but the problem remains the same...

Comment: Was your device connected to internet?

Comment: Yess it was connected.. Google Play Services is also supported

Comment: This Message: 00:18:40.069 10844-10844/com.example.acer.myapplication W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms 02-25 00:18:40.082 10844-11332/com.example.acer.myapplication I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6 02-25 00:18:40.082 10844-11332/com.example.acer.myapplication I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6.  I'm not understanding which error it is..

Comment: can you post your build.gradle (module:app) and build.gradle (project) ?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Google Play Services?

Comment: I got the problem  when I connect to a WiFi it's working fine... But when I use my mobile data it's not working so what's the issue dude? Can you help

Comment: vist this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86294/restrict-data-for-google-play-services) and make sure your google play services is NOT restricted from data usage.

Comment: It can be your mobile internet provider issue also, check if there is data restriction for your apps in setting

Comment: Everything is Okay... My internet connectivity is also good... But its still creating problem ...

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Firebase works perfectly in most of the devices but in some devices, it does not work at all. Only sign-in is successful, **child("key").setValue("value")** and **ValueEventListener** do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually The issue I got that it's not working with my mobile data , but when I connect to a WiFi network firebase is working fine in android.. I checked my setting also but its all correct...

Answer (score 0):

If even rules are added and this problem is happening then your firebase location is not USA and you ll have to enter the databaseURL in getInstance(URL)

Answer (score 0):

If Firebase code is not responding ReDownload your Json file from firebase project and Replace it over old one.

Delete installed apks and run again.

Worked for me.